# Use anonymous-gravatar when user avatar could not be loaded

Tags: feature-request, profile-picture, gravatar, avatar

I've found this user: [Min Min](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10237304/min-min). Maybe this user is using Google account because of:

```
<div class="gravatar-wrapper-164">
    <img src="https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/.../photo.jpg?sz=328" alt="" width="164" height="164" class="bar-sm avatar-user">
</div>
```

Since the link is broken, the image could not be loaded:

> [image]

This annoying will be applied to [his question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63965421/how-can-i-get-the-details-of-the-amount-of-power-consumed-through-metrickit), too.

---

Is it better if we use `anonymous-gravatar` to replace in this case? I mean:

```js
var avatarUri = 'https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-RhaTXtPT1aQ/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/APUIFaPNmXvVGTWjg1gOqNfVohnJfElr3Q/mo/photo.jpg?sz=328';

fetch(avatarUri).then(function (response) {
  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error('Not found!');
  }
}).catch(function () {
  // try to use anonymous-gravatar instead
  document.querySelector('.anonymous-gravatar').style.display = 'inline-block';
});
```

```css
.anonymous-gravatar {
  background-image: url('https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/unified/sprites.svg?v=fcc0ea44ba27');
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  background-position: 0 -400px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<span class="anonymous-gravatar"></span>
```

Comment: This should be tagged \[feature-request], not \[support]

Comment: Keep in mind that this effect is also observable if third party services go down, if ad block shuts down some of these third party sites (... for good reason. Especially Facebook embeds tracking _through the images_). Along with security reasons (also another meta post somewhere), there's a minor bit of a push to move _all_ profile pics to imgur to avoid ad block artifacts, third party outage artifacts, and broken link artifacts. Hasn't gone through though, so there's not much that's going to be done